# Dynamics API returning entity fields and field metadata

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

We can get the entity metadata in Dynamics API it returns all of the fields that are in the entity. What I would like to know is it possible to get the metadata for the fields at the same time?

```
var request = new RetrieveEntityRequest
            {
                EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
                LogicalName = entityName,
                RetrieveAsIfPublished = true,


            };
            var response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)_organisationService.Execute(request);

            return response != null ? response.EntityMetadata : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already answers your question but you can optimize it like this:

```
    private EntityMetadata GetEntityMetadata(string entityName, EntityFilters entityFilters, bool retrieveAsIfPublished = false)
    {
        var request = new RetrieveEntityRequest
        {
            EntityFilters = entityFilters,
            LogicalName = entityName,
            RetrieveAsIfPublished = retrieveAsIfPublished,
        };

        var response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)_service.Execute(request);

        return response?.EntityMetadata;
    }
```

If you just need Entity and Attributes metadata you can call the previous method this way:

```
        var entityMetadata = GetEntityMetadata("[entityname]", EntityFilters.Attributes | EntityFilters.Entity);
        var attributeMetadata = entityMetadata?.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WebAPI you can do so

```
[organization url]/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions?$select=DisplayName,EntitySetName&$filter=SchemaName%20eq%20%27Account%27
```

This gives you the metadataID for the account record in your CRM instance. Now use that value to create another API call and get the specific attributes for this.
Here is the next API call:

```
[organization url]/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(GUID)?$select=LogicalName&$expand=Attributes($select=LogicalName)
```